# Pass the value of info.selectionText to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension. I have this function which is triggered as a callback for the context menu click:

**background.js**

```
function setTranslation(info, tab) {
    var parseWord = 'var word = ' + info.selectionText;
    alert(parseWord); // works here
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: parseWord 
    }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            file: 'lightbox.js'
        });
    });
```

The lightbox.js for now only alerts the passed value:

**lightbox.js**

```
alert(word);
```

I'm trying to find a way to pass the value of the selection (`info.selectionText`) to content script (`lightbox.js`). It works when the value of `code` property in `background.js` is a simple string. But when I concatenate it with the value of `info.selectionText` it alerts `undefined`.

Is this because of asynchrony of the action?
Is there a way to make it work with a tweak or do I have to use message passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming info.selectionText is `abc`, look at the injected code: `var word = abc`. Now as you can see `abc` here is not a string, but a variable name that's not defined!

The robust solution is to use JSON.stringify that escapes embedded quotes and adds doublequotes around the string:

```
var parseWord = 'var word = ' + JSON.stringify(info.selectionText);
```